# SBT: error: not found: value npmDependencies npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq(...)

Tags: sbt, scala.js, scalably-typed

I try to start a project with [ScalablyTyped][1].

When starting `sbt` I get the following exception:

```
error: not found: value npmDependencies
```

npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq("d3" -> "5.5.0")

Here is my `plugin.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("oyvindberg", "ScalablyTyped")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.26")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalablytyped" % "sbt-scalablytyped" % "201904160530")
```

and my Builod.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

name := "Scala.js Tutorial"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6" 
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("oyvindberg", "ScalablyTyped")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(ScalablyTyped.D.d3)
npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq("d3" -> "5.5.0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npmDependencies` is a key provided by [scalajs-bundler](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/), so you'll need the following line in your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.14.0")
```

and in `build.sbt`

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)
```